# Wrong timing of event shown in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I create an event through Google Calendar API, it shows wrong timing in Calendar. How to create an event in the exact timing without considering timezone?

For example, I need to show in Google Calendar 12PM lunch at timezone `America/New_York`. What should i do so that it shows correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you always have to consider timezone. When creating your event you can specify the timezone- in your case America/New_York. You can check the sample in  [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

See the sample:

```
var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: I have included my timezone but the event timing is different when created. The time difference of the actual event timing and the event created is the time difference between the server time from which api is called and the timezone of the event